# Element access on result of getElementsByClassName/querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js, getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api

I'm trying to access to my elements by getElementsByClassName/querySelectorAll function, but I don't understand what happens when I try to get element from the result.

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('mapAtt');
console.log(cells); // [item: function]
console.log(cells[0]);  //  undefined
console.log(cells.item(0)); //  none
console.log(cells.length);  //  0

var cells2 = document.querySelectorAll(".mapAtt");
console.log(cells2);    // [item: function]
console.log(cells2[0]); //  undefined
console.log(cells2.item(0));    //  none
console.log(cells2.length); //  0
```

I read that return of this two functions isn't an array but a nodeList, but even with the item function, it doesn't work.

cells1 and cells2 show me the right thing, a list with my 22 elements, but I cannot access them with array/nodeList methods.

Elements were created with d3.js, but if I don't say mistakes, it is supposed to create well-boned HTML DOM element. So why doesn't it work?

Comment: The returned HTMLCollection is simply empty. You've to check the spelling of the class name, and make sure there are elements with the said class name at the time you create the collection.

Comment: You are trying to get SVG nodes?

Comment: Yes, it's SVG elements

Comment: CSS selectors won't traverse DOM boundaries -- the HTML document and the SVG document are different DOMs. Instead of `document`, use the root element of the SVG to call the selector on.